# CommandText Parameter is not replaced by provided value / error Insufficient parameters supplied

Tags: c#, sqlite, vsto

To test SQLite I created a very simple SQLite DB (Verion 3) with one Table and two columns (ID int, UserInput TEXT)... ID is auto increment.

I want to insert a value from a user input which is a text box however when I check the returned CommandText the parameter is not replaced but remains as "(@paramInput)"

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
            {
                string strValue = editBox1.Text;
                SQLiteCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into main.TestTable (UserInput) values (@paramInput)";

                //replace @paramInput by using AddWithValue
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramInput", strValue);

                //check result before 
                MessageBox.Show(cmd.CommandText);
                
                //write to DB
                cnn.Execute(cmd.CommandText);
            }
        }
```

I have also tried using Parameters.Add:

```
                //replace @paramInput by using Add
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@paramInput", DbType.String);
                cmd.Parameters[0].Value = strValue;
```

but again the CommandText remains as:
"insert into main.TestTable (UserInput) values (@paramInput)"
obviously resulting in error message "error Insufficient parameters supplied" when sent to the DB.

What am I missing? I've looked at various examples and they seem all to fill the parameters either by AddWithValue or Parameters.Add. Sure I could use C# parameters on the query but at least out of curiosity would like to understand what I do wrong.

System.Data.SQLite.Core 1.0.116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to call `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` instead of `cnn.Execute(cmd.CommandText);` because you trying to execute the text you set to `cmd.CommandText` "insert into main.TestTable (UserInput) values (@paramInput)" and parameter has not been replaced by the real value.

```
using (SQLiteConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
{
    string strValue = editBox1.Text;
    SQLiteCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into main.TestTable (UserInput) values (@paramInput)";

    //replace @paramInput by using AddWithValue
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramInput", strValue);

    //check result before 
    MessageBox.Show(cmd.CommandText);
                
    //write to DB
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```